# Camel, get local file with scheduler does not work - camel

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, apache-camel

I have those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

I also added this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have a simple route:

```
      from("file:C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3\\ff.txt?scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0/3 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")
                .routeId("testRoute")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "******\n*******\n******File asdsaw name : fsa");
```

It should call this method per 3 seconds but i cant see any logs with **** or with "testroute".

What i want to do is checking local folder according to quartz. If i can success this, i will try FTP but now even it cant work for local folder.

The path is correct because i can get file with

```
File initialFile = new File("C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3\\ff.txt");
            InputStream targetStream = null;
            List<String> fileAsLines = null;


            targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

File endpoint syntax is:

```
file:directoryName[?options]
```

See [File Component documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html):

> **Only directories**
>
> Camel supports only endpoints configured with a starting directory. So the **directoryName** must be a directory. If you want to consume a single file only, you can use the **fileName** option, e.g. by setting `fileName=thefilename`

So replace `file:C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3\\ff.txt?scheduler=...` with `file:C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3?fileName=ff.txt&scheduler=...`

Also depending on your Camel version you may need to replace spaces in cron expression with `+` like `scheduler.cron=0/3+0/1+*+1/1+*+?+*`. And if you want file to poll every 3 seconds, then the expression can be probably simplified to `0/3+*+*+*+*+?`

Comment: It shut down with error `due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: 0/3 * * * * ? of type: org.apache.camel.spi.ScheduledPollConsumerScheduler`  for

 `from("file:C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3?fileName=ff.txt&scheduler=0/3+*+*+*+*+?")
                .routeId("asfasafsRoute")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "******\n*******\n******File asdsaw name : fsa");` I want to see log to understand if it is worked, maybe i should create an output or `to`

Comment: You had scheduler option correct first time, why you have modified this now? Final uri for consumer should be `from("file:C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3?fileName=ff.txt&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0/3+*+*+*+*+?")` for Camel 2.x and `camel-quartz2`. Or `from("file:C:\\dev\\Repository\\ware3?fileName=ff.txt&scheduler=quartz&scheduler.cron=0/3+*+*+*+*+?")` for camel 3.x and `camel-quartz`